# Change style of single line node in openlayers 2

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, gis

I have a layer in Openlayers which allows a user to draw a line with nodes appearing at each vertex. For example:

[image]

I want the first node to appear different than the rest of them, however, to denote the start of the line. I am using a styleMap to generate the layer style but cannot seem to overwrite the first node's attributes.

Here's my code for the style map:

```
   var myDefault = {
        strokeColor: "#FF9900",
        fillColor: "#FF9900",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 4,
        fillOpacity: .9,
        pointRadius: 6
    };

    var myStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
       "default": new OpenLayers.Style(myDefault, {context:context})
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an custom style function, instead of just using unprocessed feature attributes. To do this you have to define 'context' property in your OpenLayers.Style, eg with label condition.

```
var defStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
strokeColor: "#ee9900", 
strokeWidth: 2, 
fillColor: "#ee9900", 
pointRadius: 5 , 
strokeWidth: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    label: '${label}',
    fontSize: '11px',
    fontColor: '#575555',
    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
    labelAlign: 'cm',
    labelOutlineWidth: 2
},
{
 context: {
        label:function(feature) {
            if(feature.attributes['measure']) {
                return feature.attributes.measure+" "+ feature.attributes.units;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
}
});
```

You can put any attibute for firts nodes and search it,for apply your custom style.

Comment: It's been a while since I've touched this code. You're suggesting using labels to add the differentiation? That could work, so I up-voted your answer. I wasn't as explicitly clear as I should have been in asking my question I guess, but I was really hoping for a difference in shape or color.